# Android library duplicate entry: okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, picasso

I am using Picasso library for images in my android library, and if i run app for API 26 it compiles okay it runs and everything is perfect, if i run for API 21 (5.0) i always receive `duplicate entry: okio/AsyncTimeout$1.class`

I already excluded in my gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
```

But no success, if i assemble in terminal i get same error, only libraries i use in my lib project are exoplayer and picasso (others are support libraries) I also tried to remove Picasso then it builds normally. Is it maybe connected that the other libraries of main project are causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in project level grandle:

```
configurations{
        all*.exclude module: 'okhttp'
        all*.exclude module: 'okio'
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention yes, that i tried this too, and still same error.